# Why is initialization of nested loop control variables a must in Java?

Tags: java, initialization, nested-loops

I wrote a simple "find number in multidimensional array" that is included in the official java tutorial. here's the code included in the tutorial:

```
class LabeledBreak {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] numbers = {
            {22, 34, 675, 23, 23},
            {34, 76, 98, 23, 11},
            {65, 234, 87, 23, 76}
        };

        int searchFor = 123;
        boolean found = false;
        int i;
        int j = 0;  // <-- this line

search:
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
               for (j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
                if (searchFor == numbers[i][j]) {
                    found = true;
                    break search;
                }
               }
        }

        if (found == true)
            System.out.println("Found " + searchFor + " at index " + i + ", " + j);
        else
            System.out.println(searchFor + " not found!!!");
    }
```

I couldn't understand what's the point of initializing "j" here. I tried removing the initialization statement and make it just a declaration one. But I got that error:

"variable j might not have been initialized"

Why do I have to initialize "j"? why didn't "i" require initialization as well?

Answer (score 11):

Well, if `numbers.length` was 0, the inner loop would never run and thus `j` would never be initialized, i.e. you'd never reach the statement `j = 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't fit this into a comment so I have placed the code here.

IMHO its best to use structures where you don't run into these issues.

```
FOUND: {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
            if (searchFor == numbers[i][j]) {
                System.out.println("Found "+searchFor+" at index "+i+", "+j);
                break FOUND;
            }
    System.out.println(searchFor + " not found!!!");
}
```

The scope of the variable is limited to where it can be used safely.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
int j = 1234567;
int end = -100;
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        System.println("Hello.");
System.println("j is "+j);
```

Try different values of `end`. Notice when the output is `1234567`.

Answer (score 0):

**Why Java cares to forbid reading of uninitialized variables?**

Such code constructs tend to be non-deterministic, therefore hard to debug and therefore unreliable.  Furthermore, indiscriminate stack memory reuse could lead to security leaks.

Java Language Specification, Section 16, defines what makes a variable "definitely assigned before use", essentially by looking at code flow (syntactical constructs), but ignoring contents of other variables even if known, and ignoring what exact methods are being called along the way.

**But I always initialize `j`.**

Yes you do.  But to prove it, you need to dig into the initial content of `numbers`, know how the `length` method works, and even rule out the possibility of other threads getting hold of a reference to `numbers` and modifying the array while the main thread executes.

**But I do not access `j` outside of the code path when `found` was set and, consequently, `` `j `` was initialized.**

As you say.  But JLS Section 16 considers code structure only, not into values of other variables such as `found`.

**Why is `i` any different?**

Initialization of `i` is purely syntactically guaranteed to be the first thing that happens in the outer loop, even if its body (purely hypothetically) does not execute at all.

**What if my Java compiler is smart enough to see that I do not access any uninitialized variables?**

This does not change anything as far as JLS Section 16 is concerned.  Your compiler is not allowed to let you save on such formalistic initializers, because the program might then not be portable to other Java compilers that may not be equally smart.